# finding a maximum result after comparing two different dates in business objects webi

Tags: business-intelligence

I would like to seek someone's help with Business objects Webi reports and how to create a variable that looks at two fields, compares them and returns a specific value.

For example.

I would like the report to look at DateA then look at DateB.(DateB can have many dates) Then return the latest date that comes right before DateA

ID..............DateA.............DateB..............IntendedResults
  aaa............1/3/19.............1/6/19..............1/2/19
aaa............1/6/19.............1/4/19..............1/4/19
aaa............1/7/19.............1/2/19..............1/4/19
bbb............1/1/19............1/6/19..............(blank)
bbb............1/9/19.............1/9/19..............(blank)

I created a max for each variable

=Max([DateB]) ForEach([Id]) Where( [DateB]<[DateA])

But I keep returing the wrong results showing 0's and 1's.  Please help.

Thank you